# How to pass a method on cases i dont need to use Laravel,Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: laravel

Hi there I have this problem on Laravel, I don't know how to explain it but I'll give my best, so forgive me if I am not to clear.

I have this on my controller for uploading images:

```
public function setUniqueNameAttribute(){
        $this->unique_name = md5(Auth::user()->id . time());
    }
public function getUniqueNameAttribute(){
    return $this->unique_name;
}

public function uploadImage($request, $element, $id) {

    if ($request->hasFile('question_image') || $request->hasFile('image_path') || $request->hasFile('avatar') || $request->hasFile('contact_image')) {


        $thumbnailsRules = require_once __DIR__ . '/ThumbnailRules.php';
        $this->setUniqueNameAttribute();
        if($element == 'questions'){
            $ImageToUpload = $request->file('question_image');
        }elseif($element == 'answers'){
            $ImageToUpload = $request->file('image_path');
        }elseif($element == 'users'){
            $ImageToUpload = $request->file('avatar');
        }elseif($element == 'contacts'){

            $ImageToUpload = $request->file('contact_image');
        }


        //create folders if they do not exist
        foreach ($thumbnailsRules as $key => $rule) {
            if (File::exists(storage_path('/app/public/institutions/' . $this->institution_storage . '/images/' . $element . '/' . $id . '/' . $rule['name'] . '/')) == false) {
                Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('/institutions/' . $this->institution_storage . '/images/' . $element . '/' . $id . '/' . $rule['name']);
                Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('/institutions/' . $this->institution_storage . '/images/' . $element . '/' . $id . '/original/');
            }
        }
        //save the photos to the server
        $image = Image::make($ImageToUpload);
        $image->save(storage_path('/app/public/institutions/' . $this->institution_storage . '/images/' . $element . '/' . $id . '/original/' . $this->getUniqueNameAttribute() . '.jpeg'));
        foreach ($thumbnailsRules as $key => $rule) {
            $image = Image::make($ImageToUpload)->resize($rule['width'], $rule['height'], function ($c) {
                $c->aspectRatio();
                $c->upsize();
            });
            $image->save(storage_path('/app/public/institutions/' . $this->institution_storage . '/images/' . $element . '/' . $id . '/' . $rule['name'] . '/' . $this->getUniqueNameAttribute() . '.jpeg'));
        }
    } 
}
```

This works fine for the question_image, image_path and avatar because this I use after I am logged in so I can use this:

```
 $this->setUniqueNameAttribute();
```

But for contact image I have to use this before logged in so I don't need to use this:

```
$this->setUniqueNameAttribute();
```

This gives me this error:

```
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
```

Is there a way to pass through this without getting an error..?

Comment: Maybe because you use `Auth::user()->id` in your `setUniqueNameAttribute` method and your not logged ? You can generate a unique name only based on the actual date and time

Comment: You may use Auth::guest() and control then using "IF" condition

Comment: What unique name would you give to the image if the user isn't logged in?

Comment: `if(Auth::check()) { $this->setUniqueNameAttribute(); }  else { //something else }`

Comment: @ab_ab works perfect thank you.